# How can I automate a feature only occurs in android app using Python

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation

I'm trying to automate a feature that only shows in an android app, Is there a way to get it with selenium?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is to use Appium and Appium inspector